# Java convert ArrayList to int array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to convert my arraylist to a double array[].
Why can't I cast with this method, what is wrong?

```
public static void convert(ArrayList list, double array[]) {



    array = new double [list.size()];

    for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {

        array[x]=(double) list.get(x);

    }

}
```

I get this error message

```
String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

I have this peace of code that does not work if I change fropm raw type ArrayList to Double, maybe suggestions to change this code?

```
getTest().addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
```

Comment: What type of values should be in `ArrayList list`?  Are they `doubles`?  For the sake of clarity, can you provide a code snippet which uses your `convert` function?

Comment: I provided the piece of code, it reads from a file and saves the integers to an arraylist.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
array[x]=Double.parseDouble(list.get(x));
```

Comment: How this will compile? Double.parseDouble takes String argument. list.get(x) returns Object.

Comment: this convert string to double

Comment: this line to convert string to double in correct way to avoid String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double, so I tried to change code and fix it

Answer (score 1):

Exception message says it - your ArrayList contains String values. You should use generics as `ArrayList<String>` to prevent this runtime failures

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply casting on `String` to make it double like this -

```
array[x]=(double) list.get(x);
```

Your `list` is an `ArrayList` of `Stirng`. So you have to convert the each `String` item from the `list` to `double` like this -

```
public static void convert(ArrayList list, double array[]) {

    array = new double [list.size()];

    for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {

       array[x]=Double.parseDouble((String)list.get(x));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive got the idea. I just convert my ArrayList to ArrayList
Then your code examples will work same as mine...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public static void convert(ArrayList list, double array[]) {

    array = new double [list.size()];

    for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) 
    {
        Object value = list.get(x);
        if(value instanceof String)
        {
            array[x]=Double.parseDouble(value.toString());
        }
        else if(value instanceof Double)
        {
             array[x]=(double) list.get(x);
        }
        else if(value instanceof Integer)
        {
             array[x]=(int) list.get(x);
        }

    }    
}
```